# Create appendix in Lyx

Tags: latex, lyx

I am trying to create appendix in Lyx. I use 'Document->Start Appendix Here' just before the beginning of the appendix text, and I can see that the text before the Bibliography is wrapped in an appendix box. However, when I print the document, the text appears the same way as the main body text, i.e. no indication whatsoever that these are part of appendix. Any suggestion what I may have missed? I have also tried inserting '\appendix' before the appendix text, but it doesn't work either.

In addition, how does the section numbering work in appendix? Can I simply organise the sections using the dropdown list

Answer (score 21):

You can use the dropdown menu to insert either a chapter or a section title inside the appendix box you created, depending on your document class. This is the text that will show up in the table of contents. Appendices are sequential by letter: A, B, C... There is no longer any need to use `\appendix` code in Lyx as this is done automatically behind the scenes when adding an appendix box.

Comment: For the application numbering (A, B, C...) letter to appear, you must use the "Numbered Section style" (document style: Standard Article).